# Is it possible to change a close reason after a question has been closed. (And would you want to)?

Tags: support, close-reasons, moderator-abilities

[What kind of application would benefit from being written in F# opposed to the more conventional languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322054/what-kind-of-application-would-benefit-from-being-written-in-f-opposed-to-the-mo) was closed for being subjective/argumentative. I saw potential in the question and tried to re-word it to remove the subjectiveness, but unfortunately by that point the question already had several close votes, and it was quickly shut down.

Now, as it happens, I (and others) have since uncovered duplicates that pretty much answer it.

The organisational part of my brain is telling me that this question is now incorrectly classified. Personally, I would like to see it reclassified and closed as "exact duplicate".

Is this possible? Can moderators do it?

(Also, perhaps it doesn't matter, the dupes are listed in the comments, so it doesn't really make much difference.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to reopen it, and then close it again. A mod will gladly do it for you, since moderator votes are binding and don't require other 4 people to agree, so they can re-open and re-close in a matter of seconds.

Flag it, and ask for the reason to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just edit in a "Possible Duplicates" section containing the links. This adds the useful information about duplicates to the question - that it was closed by a differing reason isn't really all that relevant.

Comment: the auto-added "Possible Duplicates" section just uses this Markdown formatting for each link: `"> [Link Title](http://linkurl)  "` .. note the blockquote opening and double-space ending on each line.