# How do I revert/change my vote to close a question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
>   [Is it possible to change a close reason after a question has been closed. (And would you want to)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40387/is-it-possible-to-change-a-close-reason-after-a-question-has-been-closed-and-wo)

I voted to close a question and specified wrong reason by mistake. Now, when I go to "close" menu I cannot change anything. How can I edit my vote or revert it at all?

Comment: Don't worry. What's important is that if the question needed to be closed it was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible; once you voted, you cannot change the reason for closing the question.

This should not be a problem, as the question is closed for the reason that is chosen from the majority of the users who voted to close it, or the reason chosen from a moderator. In the case there is a reason that is chosen from the majority of the voters, then the first chosen reason is the one used to close the question.