# Allow unlimited "Possible duplicate of" actions without actually voting

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow same user to add multiple links as possible duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/allow-same-user-to-add-multiple-links-as-possible-duplicates)

When seeing a dupe question, I sometimes come up with more than one duplicate to close it with. In other cases, I hastily vote to close as "Not a real question" or "Not constructive" before realizing I could just look up a dupe instead.

In both of these cases, I can no longer suggest a duplicate. That's by design because I can't cast a second vote - makes sense, of course. However, if I could suggest additional dupes without them actually casting another vote,

- the "possible duplicate of" comment would be auto-generated for me
- the dupe I identified will show up in the closing dialog for other users who still have their vote

Comment: Hmm, although I guess that's not as applicable to your second case. In that case though, I'm a bit wary of letting people "change" their vote, even if that's not technically how it'd work.

Comment: @Tim oh, and I had even upvoted that one. Heh. I guess it's pretty much a dupe for most intents and purposes... not sure

Comment: Partially related to the second point: [Is it possible to change a close reason after a question has been closed. (And would you want to)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40387)

Comment: Don't be hasty?

Comment: @Robert WRONG ANSWER ಠ_ಠ

Comment: lol . . . . . .